# Is it possible to extract an average and a dispersion (SD) value from the similarity matrix obtained with Quanteda?

Tags: matrix, similarity, quanteda

quanteda syntax:

```
tstat_q <- textstat_simil(dfmat_q, method = "cosine", margin = "documents")
tstat_q
```

Matrix example:

```
text1 text2 text3 text4 text5 text6 text7 text8 text9 text10 text11 text12 text13 text14
text1 1.000 0.163 0.2919 0.383 0.395 0.542 0.178 0.267 0.292 0.179 0.1279 0.229 0.220 0.320
text2 0.163 1.000 0.5959 0.213 0.427 0.255 0.467 0.272 0 0.274 0 0.216 0.403 0.245
text3 0.292 0.596 1.0000 0.399 0.582 0.565 0.609 0.487 0.159 0.466 0.0889 0.349 0.389 0.313
text4 0.383 0.213 0.3993 1.000 0.486 0.617 0.442 0.464 0.354 0.350 0.1485 0.291 0.382 0.418
text5 0.395 0.427 0.5817 0.486 1.000 0.606 0.487 0.504 0.347 0.416 0.2231 0.338 0.319 0.372
text6 0.542 0.255 0.5652 0.617 0.606 1.000 0.371 0.487 0.291 0.326 0.1778 0.257 0.298 0.396
text7 0.178 0.467 0.6091 0.442 0.487 0.371 1.000 0.466 0.185 0.426 0.1354 0.380 0.460 0.381
text8 0.267 0.272 0.4865 0.464 0.504 0.487 0.466 1.000 0.296 0.373 0.1421 0.382 0.439 0.400
text9 0.292 0 0.1589 0.354 0.347 0.291 0.185 0.296 1.000 0.298 0.3926 0.335 0.258 0.305
text10 0.179 0.274 0.4663 0.350 0.416 0.326 0.426 0.373 0.298 1.000 0.1907 0.374 0.540 0.268
text11 0.128 0 0.0889 0.148 0.223 0.178 0.135 0.142 0.393 0.191 1.0000 0.188 0.117 0.213
text12 0.229 0.216 0.3488 0.291 0.338 0.257 0.380 0.382 0.335 0.374 0.1877 1.000 0.367 0.291
text13 0.220 0.403 0.3891 0.382 0.319 0.298 0.460 0.439 0.258 0.540 0.1170 0.367 1.000 0.384
text14 0.320 0.245 0.3128 0.418 0.372 0.396 0.381 0.400 0.305 0.268 0.2132 0.291 0.384 1.000
```

Answer (score 1):

The underlying function of `quanteda.textstats::textstat_simil()` is `proxyC::simil()` It returns a sparse matrix and has `rowSds()` and `colSds()` to compute standard deviations of rows and columns.

```
require(proxyC)
mat <- matrix(c(1, 3, 5, 6, 1, 2), ncol = 3)
sim <- simil(mat, margin = 2, method = "cosine")
rowSds(as(sim, "dgTMatrix")) # the same as apply(sim, 2, FUN = sd)

# [1] 0.03713724 0.03467199 0.01342248
```

Comment: But worth keeping in mind that the output matrix is symmetric. So if you want a mean or sd of just unique pairs, exclude the upper triangle and the diagonal.